# Incorrect return type (OCMReturnValueProvider) from OCMock stubbed method

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I have a set of unit tests for my project that are built around OCMock (3.1.1 via CocoaPods), Xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1. Within on the tests, I stub a method in a partially mocked class using the following line of code (where PROJECTSTAEINTERVAL is some #defined value).

```
OCMStub([partialMockRequest getLocalProjects]).andReturn([NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:PROJECTSTALEINTERVAL/2]);
```

The normal getLocalProjects method returns an NSDate, so there shouldn't be anything strange with the type of the return value in the stubbed method. Initially there were no problems with this unit test in that the NSDate was returned where as it should be getLocalProjects was called from another method:

```
NSDate *projectDateInLocalStore = nil;

// get the local projects and see what the the latest date is.
projectDateInLocalStore = [self getLocalProjects];
```

However as a new person on the project tried to run the same unit test using the same code base (i.e pulled from git), the unit test failed because the object that was being returned from getLocalProjects was not the correct type and calls to NSDate functions threw an exception. The type returned is shown below:

[image: incorrect value returned]

Since we were both working from the same code, we figured it was a setting in the project, but could not figure out where the settings were different. Yesterday, without changing anything to the best of the knowledge, my unit test started to fail and I am also now seeing the OCMReturnValueProvider type being returned from my stubbed method. The only thing that did happen was that my pod setup went out of sync and had to be rebuilt.

I can fix the problem by changing the unit test as follows:

```
NSDate *staleDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:PROJECTSTALEINTERVAL/2];
OCMStub([partialMockRequest getLocalProjects]).andReturn(staleDate);
```

Although I have a workaround, I was curious if there was something I was doing initially that was incorrect that was causing the strange behaviour. Anyone seen this type of thing before? Any ideas why the second approach works now, but the first does not?

Thanks for your help